# Do we have rings for which $(I:a)=(0:a)$ or for which $(I:a)\cong(0:a)?$

Tags: ring-theory, modules

I have been reading a book on Macoy rings and I saw these definitions for the annihilator sets:  let $R$ be a ring and $I$ an ideal of $R$.
$$(I:a)=\{r\in R: ra\in I\}~~\text{and}~~(0:a)=\{r\in R: ra=0\}.$$
My question is, do we have rings for which $$(I:a)=(0:a)$$ or for which
$$(I:a)\cong(0:a)?$$

Comment: McCoy rings rather than "Macoy rings" right...?

Comment: You're missing a couple of quantifiers that makes answering your question problematic. "Do we have rings for which ... " for all $a$ and $I$? or just for all $I$ and for a particular $a$?

Comment: You already see that if the equality holds, $I$ must annihilate $a$, right?  Otherwise, equality can't hold...

Comment: Actually, it should be for some $I\neq \{0\}$ with $a\notin I$